# How to speed up exporting in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: python, export, satellite-image, google-earth-engine, google-python-api

I need to download a bunch of Landsat images from Google Earth Engine, and I'm doing it in its Python API with

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image(IMAGE, NAME, config=CONFIG)
task.start()
```

Though it's working, the speed is extremely slow. The size of my images is around 70kb, but each takes 4 min or longer. Currently this happens in a for loop, so how can I, if possible, pack up multiple images as one task? Or other ways to speed up this process?

Comment: I change from local python scripts to [colab](https://colab.research.google.com). I can't say why but the response on a `.getInfo()` is several times faster ;)

Comment: If you were running a separate script for every download, then you might have been  spending a lot of time authenticating and initializing the library for every image.  In colab, that's all paid once "at the top".

Answer (score 4):

The startup costs for an export are pretty high.  If you're just exporting tiny pieces, you might be able to do it with `image.getThumbnail` for RGB visualized images, or `image.getDownloadURL()` for raw numbers.

The `getThumbnail()` function will give you a PNG or JPEG and `getDownloadURL()` will give you a zipfile with the bands as individual geotiffs.  Note that both are unreliable for large downloads or images that take a lot of computation.  Since the image starts being computed once you access the resulting URL, there's no way to communicate failure; if something goes wrong, you just get a empty/corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. It is a process that takes place in Google's servers, so you can do nothing about it. The only thing I can think of is that: if you make unnecessary operations it may take longer, I guess. For example (a very simple one):

```
img_1 = ee.Image(A).add(ee.Image(B)).add(ee.Image(C)).subtract(ee.Image(B))

img_2 = ee.Image(A).add(ee.Image(C))
```

exporting img_1 could take longer than exporting img_2. But I'm only guessing because I don't really know what happens on the "server side".. you could ask the people who do know that in the Earth Engine Forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers).

By the way, if you use the Python API, this could be useful: https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools